# Illustrator to SVG: different shades for different browsers

Tags: adobe-illustrator, svg, transparency, file-format, browser

I have just approached the world of design and so consequently I have many doubts about certain subjects, one of them is related to nuances.

As you can see from the images below, my "project" created in Adobe Illustrator is "corrupt" once saved in SVG format:

Project components:
 [image: Project components Image]

Finished project / SVG:

### [image: Finished project / SVG Image]

---

SVG Options:
    SVG Profiles: SVG 1.1
    Options:
        Image Location: Link

---

I would kindly like to know what I'm doing wrong, if I should combine paths instead of overlapping them, or something else. Thanks for your help!

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: SVG is a bit tricky to control consistenly. Have you considered using PNG's instead ?

Comment: Yes, but right now i need svg to work

Answer (score 1):

You have ultimately to sacrafice features for consistency. A vector graphics file is not at all like an image. Its more like a computer program than a image format.

Now its near impossible to get full consistency since the programs work differently. The SVG standard does not define accurately enough how things should be drawn. Hell, even illustrator itself is not consistent between GPU render and export to a image format, let alone across adobe apps.

There is no universal way to becoming more consistent. Hell even the antialiasing algorithm varies across renderers and arguably most of them are broken.

PS it is a really bad idea to layer two exactly same things on top of eachother.

Comment: Thank you for the tip

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that this has much to do with Illustrator but rather the differences between SVG rendering in different browsers. Part of the problem may be because of the semi transparency in some of your gradients. I've noticed that browsers can render semi transparency slightly differently, so why not try creating your gradients without transparency but use solid colours instead. Obviously you will have to rethink how these are constructed.

As a general rule of thumb I've found that keeping vector graphics as simple as possible is the key to success - so if possible that means no SVG effects, such as blurs, and not using blending modes, or transparency.

Anyway, here's [a rough example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mvo8y.jpg) using firefox, edge and chrome. I checked the values by sampling the colours, and these are quite consistent.

[image]